# static variable java - all objects in an array list are given the same name?

Tags: java

say in my Island class I have

```
 private static String islandName;
 public static String getName() {
        return islandName;
    }
```

and in Class2 I have an array list of 'Islands' like so

```
public static ArrayList<Island> generateIslands(){
    ArrayList<Island> islands = new ArrayList<Island>();
    islands.add(new Island("Island0", "Everything at default"));
    islands.add(new Island("Island1", "A big Island with its people proud of its fresh produce and clear lakes"));
    islands.add(new Island("Island2", "An Island where materials are valued, and oil is in need."));
    islands.add(new Island("Island3", "Agriculture is good"));
    islands.add(new Island("Island4", "Materials are vast"));
    islands.add(new Island("Island5", "tbd"));

    return islands;
    
    
}
```

later in class2 when I print out all the islands in the array list, it shows them all as as "Island5" (but has the correct description). Why is it showing Island5 instead of Island1, Island 2 etc? Is it because I have set it as static? I am not sure how to fix this so It doesn't call all my islands 'island5'

the output:

```
 Island name: Island5 
Description: Everything at default 
Routes from this Island: 
Island name: Island5 
Description: A big Island with its people proud of its fresh produce and clear lakes 
Routes from this Island: 
Island name: Island5 
Description: An Island where materials are valued, and oil is in need. 
Routes from this Island: 
Island name: Island5 
Description: Agriculture is good 
Routes from this Island: 
Island name: Island5 
Description: Materials are vast 
Routes from this Island: 
Island name: Island5 
Description: tbd 
Routes from this Island:
```

Comment: The `static` modifier means that all instances of the class share the same value. You should remove the `static` if you want the values to be different for each instance of the class.

Comment: Yes, because it is static, it is a `class` variable and not an `instance` variable

Comment: Moral: don't make things `static` unless you know why you're doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have it static, because when you change a static value it changes it in the class not in the specific object. So when generating your last island with name `"Island5"` you overwrite all other island. if it has to be static, then a fix would be:

```
public String islandName;
private static Island instance;

public Island(...) {
  ...
  instance = this;
}

public static String getName() {
  return instance.islandName;
}
```

Although you wouldn't really need it to be static, because if you have it in a list you can get an instance by looping through it.

So in conclusion, you should just remove the static from both declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `isLandName` attribute is static, this means it is a class attribute and all the instances of the class share just 1 copy of this attribute so it will store the most recent value you gave it if you make the attribute non-static it will work as intended.

```
 private String islandName;
   public String getName() {
    return islandName;
    }
```